# randomized quicksort: probability of low partition size 1

Tags: algorithm

In a randomized quicksort the probability to get the low partition of size 1 turns out to be 2/n.
I have been trying to get my head around this but couldn't figure out how.

The expression I get is:

```
X = low partition size
P(X=1) = 1/n + 1/n
[Summation(i = 2 to n) 
{
  (n-i Comb i-1)/(n-1 Comb i-1)
}
]
```

this reduces to:

```
= 1/n + 1/n[(n-2)/(n-1) + (n-3)(n-4)/(n-1)(n-2) + ...]
```

How to move further?
Is my approach and expression correct?

Answer (score 1):

> the probability to get the low partition of size 1 turns out to be 2/n

It depends on what you mean by "low partition of size 1". If you look at the [worst case for quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Worst-case_analysis):

> The most unbalanced partition occurs .. if the pivot happens to be the smallest or largest element in the list

With a uniform choice, the probability of choosing the lowest element is *1 / n*, as is the probability of choosing the highest element. Since these are disjoint events (when the elements are not all the same), then the total probability is their sum: *2 / n*.

The probability that the left side of the partition is 1, is half of that: *1 / n*.

Comment: I thought so as well. so, probability of getting 1, n-1 (or n-1, 1) would be 2/n makes sense but so would be getting q, n-q (or n-q, q). I was studying this from TH Cormen and it explicitly states that probability of getting 1, n-1 is twice that of getting any other configuration. Ref. section 8.2 (value of q = 1 is twice as likely as any other value of q)

Comment: @Skartik I'll check it out. It might be because of the way pivot is defined in partition of that particular version. In the future, if your question depends on a particular version of an algorithm, I suggest you mention that in the question explicitly.

Comment: Yes please. Thanks

Comment: @skartik So I checked it before in CLRS, and in both versions I saw, quicksort is in ch. 7, and I can't find your claim there. Could you post in your question 1. The pseudocode used in your version and 2. a quotation of the statement? Thanks.

Comment: Its chapter 8 for me in Cormen: Analysis of Quicksort->Average case analysis->Analysis of partitioning-> a recurrence for the average case

Comment: I can mail you a copy of cormen that I am using.

Comment: Ok. I figured this out. For 1, n-1 prob is 1/n but for rank(pivot) > 1 also there is one way in which 1, n-1 partition would happen. Hence, 2/n